# Replacing space with underscore at specific positions only, using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I have some `CREATE` statement like

```
CREATE TABLE [a b]{ }
CREATE TABLE [anything everything]{}
```

Now I want to replace the space within the brackets with `_`, i.e. the output should be:

```
CREATE TABLE [a_b]{ }
CREATE TABLE [anything_everything]{ }
```

I tried using `sed`, but I am not able to preserve the strings.

Comment: Did you already tried something? Please share!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimal sed:

```
sed 's/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/'
```

If you may find more than one space between brackets:

```
sed ':a;s/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/;ta'
```

And as [commented by glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/106061791?noredirect=1), for BSD version of `sed`, semicolon don't work as expected. But you could write something like:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(\[[^] ]*\) /\1_/' -e 'ta'
```

But I repeat: you have to use this *branch loop* only if you expect to find more than one space (one replacement) between brackets ( `Create table [more than one space] {` ).

Comment: Nice. With the default BSD sed on Mac OSX, I found I had to replace the semicolon following `:a` with a newline.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for warning me about BSD sed on MacOS! I've edited my answer, adding a version tested on Mac.